# How to use external xml by XmlPullParser and LayoutInflater on Android?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, xmlpullparser

I want to use external(like /storage/sdcard0/main.xml) xml as Layout by LayoutInflater.
So I found use external xml by XmlPullParser. But It didn't work!!

How to write xml source which is operating on XmlPullParser and LayoutInflater?

Comment: could you post your code?

Answer (score 3):

LayoutInflater does not work on arbitrary xml at runtime.  See the comment on [LayoutInflater.inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).

> **Important**   For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime.

The platform performs a downcast in [Resources.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#L1362) that makes this assumption.

```java
// XXX note that for now we only work with compiled XML files.
// To support generic XML files we will need to manually parse
// out the attributes from the XML file (applying type information
// contained in the resources and such).
XmlBlock.Parser parser = (XmlBlock.Parser)set;
```